Is this a valid way of showing that $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n\rangle\cong \mathbb C$?
I know there are many ways of showing this isomorphism but I am wondering if this following one works.
Define a ring homomorphism $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]\rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $x_i\mapsto a_i$, then this factors through the quotient to give a map $\phi:\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n\rangle$.
Now let $\mathbb C\hookrightarrow \mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be the inclusion, and compose with the proejction $\pi:\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]\rightarrow \mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n\rangle$ to obtain a map $\psi:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n\rangle$.
I will show that these are inverses of one another. Let $z\in \mathbb C$, then $\psi(x)=[z]\in \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n]$, the map $\phi$, then take $\phi([z])$ clearly equals $z$ so $\phi\circ \psi$ is the identity. Now let $[p]\in \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n\rangle$, then $[p]$ can be written as:
$$[p]=\sum_{i_1\cdots i_n}[z_{i_1\cdots i_n}]\cdot [x_1]^{i_1}\cdots [x_n]^{i_n}$$
so:
$$\phi([p])=\sum_{i_1\cdots i_n}z_{i_1\cdots i_n}\cdot a_1^{i_1}\cdots a_n^{i_n}$$
applying $\psi$ we obtain that:
$$\psi\circ\phi([p])=\sum_{i_1\cdots i_n}[z_{i_1\cdots i_n}]\cdot [a_1^{i_1}]\cdots [a_n^{i_n}]$$
However, in $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\langle x_1-a_1,\dots, x_n-a_n\rangle$ we have $[a_i^{i_1}]=[x_i]^{i_1}$ implying that $\psi\circ \phi([p])=[p]$ so $\psi\circ \phi$ is the identity and thus both are isomorphic.
In particular I am worried that this is incorrect as most other proofs I have seen rely on polynomial division, or apply Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and Zariski's lemma (which kind of feels like taking a sledgehammer approach), but I guess these also prove that every maximal ideal is of the form above, which my proof does not.

Your approach seems similar to the first answer here.

Yes, it is much easier to prove that $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)\cong k$ than Nullstellensatz, and this is true for any field $k$ regardless of whether it is algebraically closed. I believe what you did is correct, and certainly these maps are inverses of one another. I think you could check this just by using the generators $[x_i]$ and not bother to check for all polynomials $[p]$.

It's even true when $k$ is just a  commutative ring!
